# Web API post parameter is giving Null

Tags: asp.net, post

I'm new to web api. When I'm sending json string of 10MB, the method parameter is showing Null. if I reduce the json string size, then the parameter is showing the string, which I actually sending in Http body. When I googled, I found maxAllowedContentLength property's default value is 30000000 bytes. But my string size is far smaller than this value. Why my http post method is not taking large string as Parameter? How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Parameter for Post method, read input from http content as follows:

```
var msg = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var msgResult = msg.Result;
string reqString = msgResult.ToString();
```